# Dynamically change css style by class name

Tags: javascript, dom, classname

```
<p class="typeA build1"> Build 1 <div class="b">Complete</div></p>
<p class="typeA build2"> Build 2 <div class="b">Incomplete</div></p>
//about 6 or 7 more builds...
```

I need to access the style of build# to change the display...all are originally hidden but I hava java code that creates a string/s (ex. "build2" and "build3").
I have that string saved as "tempKey" in my JAVA code.

Then in a javascript script:

```
var tempKey = "<%=tempKey%>";
document.getElementsByClassName(tempKey).style.display = "block !important";
```

I have also tried adding a class "active" and had that class have the same style (block !important), plus a number of different ways to solve this. It seems I just can't access the element right using the java string in a javascript function.

**EDIT:**

I am accessing the right element, but it won't let me overwrite the display style from none to block. For some reason !important is not working...

Comment: When you're saying Java, do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: No. It is in Java. <%String tempKey = ..... %>.

Comment: Are you using some kind of templating framework?

Comment: Have you looked at your *resulting* HTML DOM in the browser and checked if the style is applied? We would know if it is a CSS problem or a JS-Problem.

Comment: Ok. So in my code, say in the example above the class typeA has a style display of "none". I am trying to set "build2"'s style display to "block" to overwrite it.

Comment: It's showing up that I tried to change it to block, but is crossed out and the active display style is "none" from "typeA"

Comment: My understanding is that "!important" should have solved that problem though..

Comment: If you really need "dynamic" css (i.e. changing without reload) I would use an ID`<style id="build1Styles"> ... </style>` then recreate and replace the entire contents of the element in clientside javascript. Re: your current approach, I haven't used `getElementsByClassName()` but I think it returns an array of elements, so you might need to iterate across them and set style.display on each individually

Comment: I don't think I _really_ need "dynamic" css.. for getElementsByClassName(), it may return an array, but I have also tried putting [0] to call the first element of the array. Still not the problem. I don't know why it won't let me change the style.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the selector returns an array so you need to supply the index [0].

```js
var i = 3;
var tempKey = "build" + i;
var el = document.getElementsByClassName(tempKey)[0];
el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCC00";
```

```css
ul.type-list {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

ul.type-list li.typeA {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #99AACC;
}
ul.type-list li span.b {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<ul class='type-list'>
  <li class="typeA build1">Build 1
    <span class="b">Complete</span>
  </li>
  <li class="typeA build2">Build 2
    <span class="b">Incomplete</span>
  </li>
  <li class="typeA build3">Build 3
    <span class="b">build3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="typeA build4">Build 4
    <span class="b">build4</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName()` produces an array of items. You need to index into it:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('build1')[0];
console.log(element.style);
element.style.display = "block";
console.log(element.style);
```

```css
.typeA {display:none;}
```

```html
<p class="typeA build1"> Build 1 <div class="b">Complete</div></p>
<p class="typeA build2"> Build 2 <div class="b">Incomplete</div></p>
```

And there's no need for `!important` because an individual element's style supercedes all the other styles that it would have inherited.

#### Update

The real problem here is that HTML rules don't allow `<p>` elements to contain `<div>` elements, so the browser is automatically closing the `<p>` tags for you, producing this DOM:

```
<p class="typeA build1"> Build 1 </p>
<div class="b">Complete</div>
<p></p>
<p class="typeA build2"> Build 2 </p>
<div class="b">Incomplete</div>
<p></p>
```

This makes it so that your inner `div`s aren't actually children of your `p` tags. Try using another element, like `div`s, for your outer containers.

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('build1')[0];
console.log(element.style);
element.style.display = "block";
console.log(element.style);
```

```css
.typeA {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="typeA build1"> Build 1 <div class="b">Complete</div></div>
<div class="typeA build2"> Build 2 <div class="b">Incomplete</div></div>
```

Comment: This still isn't working. Looking at the resulting HTML DOM in the browser, it picks up that I tried to change the display but is crossed out/inactive and shows that typeA wants "none".

Comment: To convert a java string to a javascript variable is this correct?    var tempKey = "<%=tempKey%>"

Comment: @kb_: See my update. And no, the code that you just posted to convert a java string to a javascript variable would break if your string happens to have a double-quote character (`"`) in it. I'd suggest you use a JSON converter library of some kind. `var tempKey = <%=JsonWriter.objectToJson(tempKey)%>;`

Comment: I will try changing the <p>. For your other suggestion: my original tempKey is a value that I pulled from an external JSON.. why would I convert it back to a JSON?

Comment: @kb_: Presumably tempKey is a Java String right? The correct JSON representation of "`say "hello"`" when JSON-serialized is `"say \"hello\""`, which is exactly what you want to have show up in your rendered output.

Comment: It is a java string yes. it may be because I am not trying to output it? I am trying to use it as a parameter for getElementsByClass(tempKey) to return that element so I can change it.